# How to go to iTunes Store?

Tags: itunes, itunes-store

I'm using iTunes 10.1.2 (17).

When i click "iTunes Store" it shows me an "App Store" and there is no visible way to go to iTunes Store (to listen music).

How to do it ?

**Update**

Thanks for quick response.

Hmm … i have only three tabs (App Store, Podcasts, iTunesU).

I think, iTunes Store is not available for my country.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Are you sure you're on the Music tab/category?

Answer (score 2):

You can change categories along the top of the window.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the iTunes application
2. Click "iTunes Store" in the sidebar
3. Click on the "Music" tab at the top of the window to filter content to music only